# Будет ли работать такой способ редактирования вопросов, требующих уточнения?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правки, новые-участники

Есть идея: когда встречаю вопрос новичка, в котором не хватает чего-то конкретного:

- Кода
- Стектрейса ошибки
- Версии используемого ПО
- Описания желаемого и фактического результатов

можно отредактировать вопрос и прямо разметить в нём места, куда нужно что-то добавить. Например, так:

> <тут описание того, что вы уже пробовали сделать по этой задаче>

> <тут описание конкретных затруднений. Приложите код фич, который вы
>   пишете и который не работает, как вы ожидаете>

> <скопируйте сюда полностью стектрейс программы, отформатируйте его
>   кнопкой `{}` или Ctrl+K>

> Добавьте код в нужные места:

```
    здесь JavaScript
    здесь CSS  
    здесь HTML
```

Вопросы:

- Поможет ли это новичкам понять, что от них требуется?
- Кто-нибудь ещё так делает?

Предложение:

- Поделать так и посмотреть на реакцию.
- При этом добавляйте вопрос в [список отслеживаемых](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2169/181472).

Важно:

- Это лучше делать до объявления вопроса требующим правки. Тогда ваша правка не отправит вопрос в очередь на переоткрытие. А когда автор заменит вашу разметку на требуемое содержимое, то вопрос закономерно пойдет в очередь на переоткрытие, где будет открыт и заплюсован.
- Но даже если вопрос уже [требует правки] - смысл всё равно есть. Особенно если эта правка сопровождается общим улучшением вопроса (форматирование, метки и т.п.)

Comment: Отличная идея! Отследить можно будет по графикам ревизий своих вопросов или ответов от участников с репутацией ниже N. Возможно, стоит составить список конкретных шаблонов на подобие «[Списка шаблонных комментариев](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1222/6)»?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky сделал список вопросов для отслеживания. Про шаблоны определенно стоит подумать. Можно даже сделать userscript, добавляющий нужные кнопочки в редактор.

Comment: это намного упросит понимание новичками как правильно задавать вопрос, совсем недавно в реальном времени видели, как задающий пытался 4 раза правильно отформатировать код и него все равно не получилось все сделать правильно.

Comment: @Alex разумеется, в вопросах по плюсам не надо вставлять сниппет и даже шаблон сниппета. Это исключительно для вебовых вопросов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ясно, подумали, что вы про шаблон)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, признавайтесь - вы придумали это уже давно, но ждали выборов, чтобы сделать этот пост))) Отлична идея)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо! Я уже так делал однажды, но не отследил результат. Сегодня вспомнил и решил вынести на обсуждение. С выборами не связано. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, верю) Надо Qwertiy напрячь (он, вроде, умеет) сделать магические кнопочки для автоматического добавления всяких таких штук в вопросы)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Идея кажется привлекательной, но я сразу вижу одну огромную проблему: один пользователь будет единолично решать, чего именно не хватает в вопросе. Это далеко не всегда так однозначно.

Возьмём для примера стандартный вопрос в стиле домашнего задания или банального простого вопроса: "Вот задачка X. Как её решить с помощью Y?" Что произойдёт? Зуб даю, сразу же несколько пользователей налетит на вопрос и налепит плейсхолдеров "вот мой код" и "у меня такая проблема". Но ведь это часто излишне!

Туда же стеки вызовов и версии ПО — кто вам сказал, что они строго обязательны или о чём-то скажут? Да, они полезны, но нужны не всегда.

Ещё хуже — заставлять автора вопроса пользоваться фрагментами кода. Это должны быть самодостаточные примеры, которые могут выполнены прямо на месте в браузере, причём интерфейс достаточно ущербный по сравнению с тем же JSFiddle. В целом, это инструмент для продвинутых пользователей. Что будет, если подсунуть его новичку? Он вставит код, только этот код будет без отступов, будет включать PHP, и практически наверняка чего-нибудь не будет хватать. Пользоваться фрагментами кода сложно.

И давайте поговорим о лени. Кто-нибудь будет вручную набирать текст под каждый конкретный случай? Нет же. Будут "шаблонные плейсхолдеры", текст которых вряд ли будет радикально отличаться от текста причин закрытия. Что увидит новичок? Что его текст испоганили каким-то дырками, которые не имеют к его проблеме никакого отношения.

В целом, идея нежизнеспособна. Всё, чего можно так добиться — это что сайт будет забит под завязку вопросами с плейсхолдерами, которые никто никогда не заполнит.

Comment: Что если то же самое делать в блоках `<!-- -->`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Те же проблемы, только последствий меньше, и вероятность, что автор заметит плейсхолдеры, примерно нулевая.

Answer (score 4):

Список экспериментальных вопросов:

Ставьте статусы: {ждем, улучшен, заброшен}

- (заброшен) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477041/181472

Comment: Пока прогресс отсутствует